# Making a simple contact box with HTML5 and php work correctly

Tags: php, html

I have a question about making these two pieces of code work together. I have gone through several days struggling to find why this produces a blank page that directs to contact.php instead of sending the email with the data. Simply The Name, Business Name and Email. I am not a php programmer and would appreciate the help, or perhaps if someone could steer me in the right direction.

HTML5 sample

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="alerts-name">Your Name</label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" id="alerts-name"  class="input" maxlength="30">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="alerts-business">Business Name</label> 
          <input type="text" name="business" id="alerts-business" class="input" maxlength="50">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="alerts-email">Your email</label> 
          <input type="text" name="email" id="alerts-email" class="input" maxlength="30">
        </fieldset>
        <label>*What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)</label><br />
        <input name="human" placeholder="Type Here">
        <fieldset>
        <br />
        <fieldset>
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

Below is the php code I am using.

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $business = $_POST['business'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $from = 'From: The Web Site';
  $to = 'myemail@site.com';
  $subject = 'Hello';
  $human = $_POST['human'];
  $body = "From: $name\n business: $business\n email:\n $email";

  if ($_POST['submit'] && $human == '4') {
  if (mail ($to, $name, $business, $email) ) {
  echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';

  } else {
  echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
  }
  } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
  echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you just confirm that this is the PHP code you have in the "contact.php" file?  Or is all of this in the same file?

You're not using the $subject variable in your PHP.  And your "human" element should probably have a type="text" (or [type="number"](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html)) attribute in the HTML too.

I've had a lot more success with the PHPMailer extension when performing tasks with email, and you can get the most recent version from [github](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer).  There's a good usage example [over there](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer#a-simple-example) to get you started.

Also, as an aside, as you're coding in HTML5, [you can safely use the new "email" type of input](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) which has some nice built-in validation:

```
 <input type="email" name="email" id="alerts-email" class="input" maxlength="30">
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your 'from' header is incorrectly formatted - this should either be:

`'From: The Website <the@website.com>';` or should simply be left out as this is an optional paramater to the `mail()` function.

You also then pass four parameters to the `mail()` function - to, name, business and email. The appropriate paramaters are listed with the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), they are:

`mail (string $to, string $subject, string $message[, string $additional_headers[, string $additional_parameters]]);`

In this sense your function should read something more like:

`mail($to, $subject, $email);`

tl;dr:

You use `$business` as part of your mail function where you should really be including the message, meaning your email body is being interpreted as the email headers and is totally incorrectly formatted.